# Why I get error hints from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I have my visual studio 2017 display red lines under many statements although the code compile fine !! any idea why and how to fix this ?

here is a picture

[image]

hover over one of the errors:

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you hover over it?

Comment: Does the `UE_LOG` macro accept 4 arguments with a format string? As @Ido mentioned, you should see detail if you hover your mouse cursor over the item.

Comment: @Idos I added a picture for one of the errors

Comment: @Kishore I have visual assistant installed but it was like that before I install it\

Answer (score 1):

Before actually compiling and linking the game UE4 runs its own Unreal Header Tool. It generates a great deal of extra code. Because of that Visual Studio sometimes doesn't find some of the symbols that will be available after generation. [There's is a page](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Development/VisualStudioSetup#intellisense,liveerrors,andsquiggles) that explains that it's normal when you work with UE4.

Also, consider this. UE4 may use a unity build so it will make a giant .cpp file out of all your source files. It may happen that all of your "false positive" errors are resolved by the order in which those source files are included. But since Visual Studio treats every source file as a separate translation unit (not unity build) it will make sure that you don't use any undefined symbols.

If squiggles bother you too much, try to include all of the headers with the necessary symbols (for example "Components/InputComponent.h") in your source file.

Comment: I am following a tutorial and in the videos the instructor does not has these squiggles so of course I prefer if I dont have them unless with a real problem

Comment: @Wel he probably had his Visual Studio customized for the earlier UE4 versions

Comment: instructor uses 4.10 and I use 4.19 but why I get these problems

Comment: did you try including headers with missing symbols as I suggested?

Comment: I dont understand how to do that or what are the missing symbols

Comment: Basically its like this: Visual Studio is giving a false positive because its dealing with so many different libraries. Some of these libraries are created at runtime (once the editor starts). The red squiggles should go away once you do a full build (build solution).